# The first row in the first column from csv file is imported with not existing space into mariadb table

Tags: csv, import, mariadb

I'm importing a csv file on windows:

```
3K;Cartridge/CHRA/Core Assy;B9DC3A;96,11;1057,21;1371,48;36,21;1602,78;54357100500;328;;;54357100500;;
3K;Cartridge/CHRA/Core Assy;D6EC42;483,95;5323,45;5603,62;10,53;6548,67;13877100500;328;;;13877100500;;
3K;Cartridge/CHRA/Core Assy;D79352;132,45;1456,95;1831,50;31,99;2140,39;53037100501;328;;;53037100501;;
3K;Cartridge/CHRA/Core Assy;D79353;119,08;1309,88;1683,33;34,94;1967,23;53037100502;328;;;53037100502;;
3K;Cartridge/CHRA/Core Assy;D79354;164,09;1804,99;2299,99;33,80;2687,88;53037100503;328;;;53037100503;;
```

in this db:

```
CREATE DATABASE db
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
  DEFAULT COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS oo (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  iid VARCHAR(255),
  prod VARCHAR(255),
  grp VARCHAR(255),
  al VARCHAR(255),
  ap VARCHAR(255),
  mp VARCHAR(255),
  ic VARCHAR(255),
  td VARCHAR(255),
  td_p INT,
  add_inf TEXT,
  INDEX( iid ),
  PRIMARY KEY( id )
);
```

with this command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'd:\\inn.csv' 
  INTO TABLE `oo`
  CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
  ESCAPED BY '\"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  ( prod, grp, ic, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @td, td_p, @dummy, @dummy, al, ap, mp, @add1, @add2 )
  SET
    td = @td,
    iid = concat( @td, '--', @prod ),
    add_inf = concat( @add1, @add2 );
```

Everything works perfect beside the first column in the first row which produces an additional space in the beginning. I don't know where it comes from. I have tried to set `prod = REPLACE( @prod, ' ', ''),` but it doesn't help. The csv file doesn't have space in the first row, firs column and is encoded in UTF-8 with BOM.

This is how the output looks like:

[image: db output]

Comment: Open your CSV file in a hex editor to look at what's at the beginning of the file. Or use Notepad++, and tell it to display all characters. It could be something other than a simple space in that location, which would explain why your REPLACE doesn't work. Without having access to the actual CSV, we can't troubleshoot the problem for you, so you're going to need to do it yourself.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm using only notepad++ :) and yes I will try hex, so you mean that this is problem only with a file and not my code?

Comment: I see you found your answer before I could reply to this comment. :-) Nicely done, and good answer as well. Notepad++ probably does what everything should, which is to discard the BOM after using it to know what encoding the file contains - it shouldn't be considered part of the file's content. That's why my first suggestion was a hex editor, which looks at raw content without any side effects.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Ken White I have found an issue and how to solve it.

In my case it was UTF-8 encoding with BOM which I thought was needed for Mariadb to import a file in the right way, but I see that it just produced this "error". Maybe it is only on Windows.

I couldn't find or see the symbol in Notepad++ but i found it in Total Commander lister and it looks like this: ï»¿

[image]

In fact it's not an error, it's just not printable sign for file encoded with UTF-8 with BOM, and everything it takes is just to convert the file to "normal" UTF-8 encoding without BOM.

I hope that this answer can help anyone who had the same problem.